# What is the best way to use the Google API to get just a user's email?

Tags: python, email, oauth, gmail, gmail-api

I'm writing a program with the gmail api and a problem I have run into is getting the currently authorized user's email address. I think I can do this with the scope `https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.email` as in http://www.hackviking.com/development/python-get-user-info-after-oauth/ but when I try that in Google's OAuth Playground it requests permission to "know who you are on Google" as well as permission to see your email address. The program doesn't need to know the user's name/info etc., it just needs the email address.

The reason I even am trying to use the userinfo.email scope is because after looking a while I can't find a way in the gmail scope to get the user's email but if there is a way that would be even better.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use the [getProfile](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/v1/reference/users/getProfile)-method, and for that you need one of the following scopes:

```
https://mail.google.com/
https://www.googleapis.com/auth/gmail.modify
https://www.googleapis.com/auth/gmail.compose
https://www.googleapis.com/auth/gmail.readonly
```

Then you can just get the email address:

**Request**

```
GET https://www.googleapis.com/gmail/v1/users/me/profile?fields=emailAddress&access_token={ACCESS_TOKEN}
```

**Response**

```
{
 "emailAddress": "foo@gmail.com"
}
```

In Python this would look like:

```
profile = gmail_service.users().getProfile(userId='me').execute()

print 'Email address of user is: %s' % profile['emailAddress']
```

Comment: Thank you so much this is exactly what I wanted. Just another question, do you know if there is there a way for me to do this in Python just using the api or will I need to use httplib or something else for the GET request?

Comment: @sj-f No problem! There is a method in the [Gmail API Client Library for Python](https://developers.google.com/resources/api-libraries/documentation/gmail/v1/python/latest/gmail_v1.users.html#getProfile), if you don't mind getting the entire Profile, not just the emailAddress. But it's not that much data, so that should work great.

Comment: Thanks again I have that working now, but I've run into another problem. Now that I have that `address = gmail_service.users().getProfile(userId='me')` I try to parse it as a JSON but the console tells me that's an object of type HTTPRequest and that I can't use it as a parameter of json.load(). The api doc says it returns an object with those attributes but I can't figure out how to get the object from the request.

Comment: @sj-f Edited the answer.

Comment: Thank you so much that solved all my problems. You're the best.

Comment: @sj-f No problem :) Good luck with your program!